# Angular2 Meteor 1.3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular

I have commented virtually everything out of my app and for some reason it continues to fail.  It seems to be an injector problem but there doesnt seems to be a good stracktrace I can use to track it down.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had imported

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

and that was causing it to screw up.  Taken out it works fine